# Program execution stopped due to segmentation fault:11

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

My program deals with accessing attributes of a structure which is defined inside a class. When I use a pointer of type struct to show the structure's attributes, it is throwing a segmentation fault and stops the execution. Though it is printing the structure's attributes fine if I just use a  variable of type struct. I tried debugging the code with `gdb` and it is showing the segmentation fault occurs at line 27 which is `poly.params->a = 1;`. Why can't we use pointers in this case or am I making a stupid mistake? Here is the sample of the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class QuadraticFunc
{
  public:
    QuadraticFunc(){};
    struct Coeff
    {
        double a;
        double b;
        double c;
    } * params;
    void ParamShow(const Coeff *params)
    {
        cout << "a: " << params->a << endl;
        cout << "b: " << params->b << endl;
        cout << "c: " << params->c << endl;
    }
    ~QuadraticFunc(){};
};

int main()
{
    QuadraticFunc poly;
    poly.params->a = 1;
    poly.params->b = 2;
    poly.params->c = 1;

    QuadraticFunc *polyPtr;

    polyPtr = &poly;

    cout << "The parameters for the first object: " << endl;
    polyPtr->ParamShow(poly.params);
}
```

Comment: Which line is the line 27? Would be easier for people going through this.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> poly.params->a = 1;
> ```

`params` has not been initialized.

Replace

```
struct Coeff
{
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
} * params;
```

with

```
struct Coeff
{
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
} params;
```

And then replace each `params->` with `params.`

Comment: Your solution still violates the "rule of 3", and is likely to lead to more bugs.

Comment: @EmployedRussian, it's a work in progress, just like your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't we use pointers in this case or am I making a stupid mistake?

Yes, you are.

```
QuadraticFunc poly;  // Your constructor leaves poly.params uninitialized
poly.params->a = 1;  // Dereferencing uninitialized pointer invokes undefined behavior.
```

> How should I fix this?

The best solution is to avoid the pointer here:

```
class QuadraticFunc
{
  public:
    QuadraticFunc(){};
    struct Coeff
    {
        double a;
        double b;
        double c;
    } params;
    ...
 };

int main()
{
    QuadraticFunc poly;
    poly.params.a = 1;
    ...
    polyPtr->ParamShow(&poly.params);
}
```

You may have a legitimate reason to have `params` as a pointer, but you have not yet shown what that reason may be.

Comment: I understand. But can you tell me how to fix it? Should I add default arguments in my constructor `QuadraticFunc()`?

Comment: @lakshya91 Updated the answer.

Comment: I don't have a good reason to use pointers for `params` but I was just playing with the code and I couldn't explain it:) Thanks for your help!

Comment: The line in the main function `polyPtr->ParamShow(&poly.params);` is giving me errors, I think we don't need to add the reference operator as there are type conversion errors coming out.

Comment: @lakshya91 The code I showed compiles *just fine*. I don't know what you did to cause "conversion errors", but it's not what my answer shows. P.S. There is no such thing as "reference operator". It's the "address of" operator.